# How to styling radio button if label goes before radio - <label></label> and then <input type="radio">

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, label

Help me please with styling radio button which comes right after label:

```
<div>
  <label for="radio">mylabel</label> 
  <input type="radio" class="myclass">
</div>
```

There is no way to put `<label>` after `<input=radio>`, or radio inside label. Need styling radio button only in priority label first.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I,m using ARI Quiz component. Quizzes generating in JavaScript and displays on page. And there is no templates for editing.

Comment: You should edit your question and describe your problem with your environment.

Comment: The real problem is with styling radio buttons, not with the order in which they appear in the source. As a side note, `<label for="radio"` works only for a control with `id="radio"`, which your control doesn't have.